# Make ball bounce and eventually come to rest

Tags: android, accelerometer, game-physics, gravity

I've written some code to move a ball around the screen using an orientation sensor. I wanted to get the ball to bounce when it hits the bottom of the screen, sort of like under gravity. Could somebody help out with implementing the physics in my existing code? Flipping the velocity doesn't seem to work. Here's my ball class:

```
package perseus.gfx.test;

import everything

public class Ball extends View  {   
RectF lol;
Paint paint, lpaint;
Bitmap bitmap;
Canvas canvas;
private float ballx = 150; 
private float bally = 140;
private double speedx = 0;  
private double speedy = 0; //ignore  
private double accx, accy=0;
private float rad = 20;
private float mult = 0.5f;
private double xv, yv, xS, yS;
int width, height;
int xmax, ymax;
int xmin, ymin;

public Ball(Context context) {
    super(context);
    lol = new RectF();
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    lpaint = new Paint();
    lpaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);                
}
public void moveBall()  {

    xv = accx * mult;
    yv = accy * mult;

    xS = xv * mult;
    yS = yv * mult;

    ballx -= xS;
    bally -= yS;

    // Collision detection
    if (ballx + rad > xmax) {

         ballx = xmax-rad;
    }         
    else if (ballx - rad < 0) {

         ballx = rad;
    }
    if (bally + rad > 2*ymax/3) //Shouldn't take up the whole screen 
    {  

        bally = 2*ymax/3 - rad;
    } 

    else if (bally - rad < 0) {

         bally =  rad;
    }                           

    try {
        Thread.sleep(20);
    }   catch(InterruptedException e) {}

    invalidate();   
}
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthM, int heightM)
{
    width = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthM);
    height = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightM);
    xmax = width-1;
    ymax = height-1;
    xmin = 0;
    ymin = 0;
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);


}
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    lol.set(ballx - rad, bally-rad, ballx + rad, bally+rad);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 2*height/3, width, 2*height/3, lpaint);
    canvas.drawOval(lol, paint);
    canvas.drawText(xv + " " + yv, 0, height/2, lpaint);
    canvas.save();
    moveBall();
    canvas.restore();

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So the key is to just add a bit of friction, just remove a tiny bit of acceleration (negative!) at each step in moveBall(). E.g.

```
    float friction = -0.001;

    xv = accx * mult + friction;
    yv = accy * mult + friction;
```

Then adjust the variable friction accordingly to suit your needs. For the collision you need to invert the velocity, e.g. bounce on bottom:

```
    bally = -bally;
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't seem to work..
I want something like what this guy has done:
http://vimeo.com/3792427
But his code seems completely different from mine. :/

Comment: The video does it like Scalar conveyed. Since the phone's accelerometer always knows which way is down due to earth's gravity. When the ball is free to move in that direction, it accelerates towards that direction. It will eventually come to a stop due to either constant friction like Scalar said or by reducing the momentum a factored amount at each wall bounce. I don't see it stepping down at the wall bounce so it is by constant friction.

Comment: @user1162533 Perhaps its something about how the variables are set by the accelerometer. Could you please provide the code where this happens?